Boundary regularity of harmonic function on Lipschitz domain
In the book 'Regularity Theory for Elliptic PDE', the authors consider the boundary regularity of the following equation:$$
\begin{cases}
 \Delta u=f&  \mathrm{in}~\Omega ,\\
 u=g&  \mathrm{on}~\partial \Omega ,\\
\end{cases}
$$
And the authors remark that
(1)If $\Omega$ is $C^{1,\alpha}$ domain, then solutions are $C^{1,\alpha}(\overline{\Omega})$;
(2)If $\Omega$ is $C^{1}$ domain, then solutions are $C^{1-\varepsilon}(\overline{\Omega})$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, but not in $C^{1}(\overline{\Omega})$ in general;
(3) If $\Omega$ is a Lipschitz domain, then solutions are $C^{\gamma}(\overline{\Omega})$ for some small $\gamma$ that depends on the Lipschitz norm of the domain, and this is optimal.\
I wonder whether there exists some exmpales to illustrate these results are optimal, or related references are welcome. Thanks in advance!
